# Using Union on multiple shapefiles to output single result

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, union

Using QGIS 2.2 and Python, I would like to use the Union algorithm on multiple shapefiles (contained in a folder *TEST*) which would then produce single shapefile containing all the data.

Currently the following code only outputs the union of the first and last file, how can I modify it so that the output of 2 layers is saved and then use that output with another layer etc?

UPDATE: The shapefiles are being processed in terms of the `clip_function` however I can't load the temp files when running the `qgis:union` algorithms. Also, an error occurs when it tries to output the Result.

```
##Model=name
##Select_folder=folder
##Cellsize=number 1000
##Result=output vector

import os
import glob
import tempfile
from qgis import utils
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

#   Create grid with defined parameters
outputs_1=processing.runalg("qgis:creategrid", Cellsize, Cellsize, 24108, 18351.157175, 258293.802316, 665638.226408, 1, 'EPSG:7405', None)

def clip_function():

#   Set directory and search for all .shp files
    os.chdir("C:\Users\TEST\DATA\\")
    for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"): 

#   Clip .shp files within directory to grid and save files as temp
        outputs_2=processing.runalg("qgis:clip", outputs_1['SAVENAME'], fname, None)
        outputs_3=processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", outputs_2['OUTPUT'], 'Rank_' + fname, 1, 10, 0, True, 1 , None)            

def binary_alg_wrapper(list_of_files,final_file_name):
    run_count=0
    temp_path=tempfile.gettempdir()
    temp_input_name="temp_input_layer"
    temp_output_name="temp_output_layer"
    temp_input_layer_filename=str(os.path.join(temp_path,temp_input_name+".shp"))
    temp_output_layer_filename=str(os.path.join(temp_path,temp_output_name+".shp"))
    for file_name in list_of_files:
        EPSG_Code_for_file=4326
        run_count+=1
        if run_count==1:
            #Copy the first file into a temp location
            temp_output_layer = QgsVectorLayer(file_name, "temp_output_layer", "ogr")
            Add_result = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(temp_output_layer)
            write_error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(temp_output_layer,temp_output_layer_filename,"system",QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(EPSG_Code_for_file), "ESRI Shapefile")
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(temp_output_layer.id())
    if run_count>1:
        #Copy the result of the last algorithm into a temp location
        old_output_layer = QgsVectorLayer(temp_output_layer_filename, "input_layer",     "ogr")
        Add_result=QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(old_output_layer)
        write_error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(old_output_layer,temp_input_layer_filename, "system", QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(EPSG_Code_for_file), "ESRI Shapefile")
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(old_output_layer.id())

        #Read in a new file and the file stored in the temp location
        input1_layer = QgsVectorLayer(temp_input_layer_filename, "input1_layer", "ogr")
        input2_layer = QgsVectorLayer(file_name, "input2_layer", "ogr")

        #Run the binary algorithm and store the result into a temp location or output location
        if run_count==len(list_of_files):
            processing.runalg("qgis:union", input1_layer, input2_layer, temp_output_layer_filename)
        else:
            processing.runalg("qgis:union", input1_layer, input2_layer, final_file_name)   

        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(input1_layer.id())
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(input2_layer.id())


path_res = tempfile.gettempdir()
file_list = [shp for shp in glob.glob(path_res + "*.shp")]
Result=(os.path.join(path_res, "result.shp"))

if Select_folder:
    clip_function()
    binary_alg_wrapper(file_list, Result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to carry out binary shapefile operations such as the one you intend to use on more than two files you can do the process in a step wise fashion using temporary files.

A TESTED peice of code is below:

```
import os
import tempfile
import shutil
import processing
import glob

def delete_shape(shape_file):
    shape_file_no_ext=os.path.splitext(shape_file)[0]
    ext_list=('shx','dbf','qpj','prj','shp','cpg')
    for extension in ext_list:
        try:
            os.remove(shape_file_no_ext+'.'+extension)
        except:
            pass

def copy_shape(shape_file,destination_shape_file):
    delete_shape(destination_shape_file)
    shape_file_no_ext=os.path.splitext(shape_file)[0]
    destination_shape_file_no_ext=os.path.splitext(destination_shape_file)[0]
    ext_list=('shx','dbf','qpj','prj','shp','cpg')
    for extension in ext_list:
        try:
            shutil.copyfile(shape_file_no_ext+'.'+extension ,destination_shape_file_no_ext+'.'+extension)
        except:
            pass

def wrapped_alg(algorithm_name,file_name_list, output_file):
    #Copy files to temp directory 
    temp_file_list=[]
    for src_file in file_name_list:
        dst_file=os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),os.path.basename(src_file))
        copy_shape(src_file,dst_file)
        temp_file_list.append(dst_file)

    #binary process on files in temp directory
    while len(temp_file_list)>1:
        temp_file=os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),'multi_merge_temp_file.shp')
        ultimate_file=temp_file_list.pop()
        penultimate_file=temp_file_list.pop()
        processing.runalg(algorithm_name, ultimate_file, penultimate_file, temp_file)
        delete_shape(penultimate_file)
        copy_shape(temp_file,penultimate_file)
        delete_shape(temp_file)
        delete_shape(ultimate_file)
        temp_file_list.append(penultimate_file)

    #copy over final file
    copy_shape(temp_file_list.pop(),output_file)

dir_to_process="C:\\test\\files\\"
output_file="C:\\test\\result\\output.shp"
file_name_list = [shp for shp in glob.glob(dir_to_process + "*.shp")]
alg_name="qgis:mergevectorlayers"
#alg_name="qgis:union"
wrapped_alg(alg_name,file_name_list, output_file)
```

NB1 this code can be used for any 'binary' processing algorithm normally run with the form

```
processing.runalg("algorithm_name", file1, file2, outputfile)
```

NB2: As written it ony works on shape files
NB3: Ensure all your shape files are in the same projection
NB4: This code is now tested on "qgis:union" and "qgis:merge"
NB5: This code is for algorithms which can run on files (additional code would be required if the inputs HAD to be loaded layers)
NB6 I do realise that for merge the following would be much more efficient but I wanted to supply a generic solution

```
processing.runalg("saga:mergeshapeslayers", file_name_list[0], ";".join(file_name_list[1:]) , outputfile)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I will test this method out. I haven't used temporary files in any of my analysis but it does make more sense to use, especially for situations like this! The CRS I'm not worried about too much at the moment but I will try to look for the code as it is, as you mentioned, better than to assume.

Comment: I've updated my code. Script seems to work almost perfectly, only problem is that I get an error when trying to output the Result.

Comment: Define "output". The intention is to wrap the binary operation onto temporary files mapped from the list of real files. Then the last resulting result file from the algorithm is the final result. Which part of that is not working? temp file read/write? algorithm result? final layer save? To some degree you need to have a good handle on how the binary algorithm handles input files and outputs results so that you wrap it correctly.

Comment: Thanks again, I understand the intention of the wrapper (although I can't say the same with my handling of it but I am learning). I've examined the temp files that are created from the clip_function but no files seem to come from the wrapper. It almost seems that wrapper function is skipped. I am testing this with only 2 files but they do not merge in any way.